# Magento 2: $.widget is not a function

Tags: checkout, javascript, jquery

When I go to the Checkout on 2 different devices, I get different console errors.

On a DELL laptop I get the error on domain.com/checkout:

- `$.widget is not a function (dataPost.min.js)`
- `Cannot read property of 'timepicker' of undefined`

On an ASUS laptop I only get the following error in on domain.com/checkout:

- `Cannot read property of 'timepicker' of undefined`

I use the same browser on both laptops. On the DELL laptop the checkout keeps showing the loading icon without any change. On the ASUS laptop the checkout works fine.

I use chrome 60 on both laptops.

I already tried merging, minifying and bundling javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

Check your script whether you have added any js file manually like 
For example,

```
require(['jquery','mage/cookies','domReady!'], function($){
```

Before adding mage/cookies here, check the head tag(In browser by clicking F12) whether its already there.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to some Javascript Conflict.

Please check whether you manually added any script link or more specific any other 'jquery.js' link.